# 405 method not allowed for web api 2 POST method

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I created the simplest `WebAPI 2` application using empty project template and Web API folder structure (in `Visual Studio 2013`). And cannot make work post request.

This is my controller

```
public class XmlFileController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Post(string payload)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    public string Get()
    {
        return "Hello world";
    }
}
```

I didn't change the Routes or anything. To my understanding, routing should work by name convention.

When calling `GET http://localhost:51356/api/XmlFile`, I get back `Status 200 OK`.

When calling `POST http://localhost:51356/api/XmlFile` with string payload and `Content-Type text/plain`, I got back `Status 405 Method Not Allowed`.

What am I missing here? Thanks.

**UPDATE:** The routing configuration is as follows:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: What does your routing config and the request code look like?

Comment: @Guanxi Thanks, fix was quick, after pointing out the problem. Updated method signature to `public IHttpActionResult Post([FormBody] string payload)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your POST is expecting a parameter - `payload` in query string. Without this parameter, it is looking for Post() function which is not defined, hence you are getting 405 error.

Comment: Solution may be to add the [FromBody] attribute to the string parameter alternatively.